# Image processing: Calculate the area of the region of interest

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to compute the area of a particular region of interest from images which are obtained from an experiment. The original data looks like this: [image]

I have to calculate the area of the region which has a darker shade compared to the rest of the image. Then using the scale bar, I have to convert the measurement into real life values. I have trimmed and binarized the images to obtain the portion of the image where I want to calculate the area.

After trimming and binarization, the image looks like this:

[image]

To get to this black and white image, I found the threshold of the image and then binarized the image such that all the pixel values < threshold value are replaced by 0 and all above threshold value are replaced by 1.

However, I cannot calculate the area of the black portion and then use the scale bar to compute the results.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: `ComponentMeasurements[AreaOfInterest, "Area"]`

Comment: As you said, you are new to SE, I want to add that it makes sense to credit the answers by accepting the best answer, when your problem is solved.

Answer (score 8):

You only need one more line for evaluation of the coverage of the colors:

```
coverage = DominantColors[yourImageBlackWhite, 2, "Coverage"]
{0.762952, 0.213876}
```

-

Edit: To answer your comment (posted as an answer), I want to add this:

You can show the number of covered pixels as well as the coverage. Using the command:

```
DominantColors[yourImageBlackWhite, 2, {"Color", "Count", "Coverage"}]
```

you obtain:

[image: DominantColors[bildsw, 2, {"Color", "Count", "Coverage"}]]

Comment: Thanks for the help. So, we use Component Measurements to find out the area. Just want to confirm that the component measurements gives the area of each non zero pixels, which in our case for the binary image is 1. Is it true?

Comment: It sorts all pixels into dominant colors and counts the pixels of each group.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that, in any analysis language, once you've got a rasterlike image and have identified the pixel values of interest, you can just count how many pixels meet the criteria, as this answer does.

Answer (score 2):

For an alternative approach to counting the number of black pixels in the binarised image you could try getting the image data and counting how many zeroes it has:

```
Count[Flatten@ImageData@yourBinaryImage,0]
```

Comment: Does not work, as it is not perfectly 0. But you can use Count[#, u_ /; u < treshold] to find pixels lower than treshold. But the result of Count[#, u_ /; u < 0.01]/Length[#] &@Flatten@ImageData@bildsw is different from the DominantColors approach.

Comment: @Philipp If I understood the OP correctly, they have a binarised image ?

Comment: But if you download the image, it isn't. The OP does not say how he created that BW-image

Comment: @Philipp Don't they say they thresholded it and then  binarised it ?

Comment: They do. I just downloaded the image