# Calculate area of black sea from image

Tags: image-processing

There is a image of [Black Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Sea) from "Google Earth".

[image]

I want to calculate area of black sea from this image using *Mathematica*

The length of yellow line  on this image is $100$ km (scale.)

I try to detect of edge of sea shape

[image]

```
 DominantColors[sea, Automatic, {"CoverageImage", "Color"}]
```

[image]

Then ([from this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71770/image-processing-calculate-the-area-of-the-region-of-interest))

```
Count[Flatten@ImageData@sea,0]

658041
```

The correct value of area is 436,402 km²

Does there exists another way to calculate  this area?

Sorry for my English. Thanks!

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100725/862)

Comment: If you measure the length of the yellow line, it should be `pixelCount * (Quantity[100,"Kilometers"] / lengthOfYellowLine)^2`. But don't expect good accuracy, since the yellow line is relatively short.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using binarize segmentation and component analysis.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZRNj.jpg"];
chan = ChanVeseBinarize[img];
comp = ComponentMeasurements[chan, {"Shape", "Area"}]
```

[image]

Components 8 and 10 are of interest. The diagonal of the shape 10 is approximately our 100 km mark. Let's use that measurement as our scaling factor.

```
scale = Sqrt@Total[ImageDimensions[c[[10, 2, 1]]]^2] // N
(*116.103*)

area = (comp[[8, 2, 2]] + comp[[10, 2, 2]])*(100/scale)^2
(*438,392.*)
real = QuantityMagnitude[
  WolframAlpha["area of black sea", {{"Result", 1}, "QuantityData"}, 
   PodStates -> {"Result__Show metric"}]]
percentError = 100 (area - real)/real
(*0.456455%*)
```

Comment: What is: `c[[10, 2, 1]]` ?

Answer (score 10):

Not really too accurate but here goes. We start as in the original post. The region of interest is the second one (or first, if we reverse 0's and 1's). We'll count zeros to get the area in terms of the pixel dimensions.

```
regions = 
  DominantColors[sea, Automatic, {"CoverageImage", "Color"}];
searegion = regions[[2, 1]];
seadata = ImageData[searegion];
seaarea = Count[seadata, 0, {2}];

yelseg = PixelValuePositions[sea, Yellow, .3]

(* Out[64]= {{512, 596}, {513, 595}, {518, 589}, {529, 576}, {539, 
  564}, {560, 539}, {565, 533}, {569, 528}, {571, 526}, {576, 
  520}, {580, 515}, {582, 513}} *)
```

This is not alone enough for the segment length. We need the red dot as well.

```
reddot = PixelValuePositions[sea, Red, .3]

(* Out[70]= {{506, 604}, {507, 604}, {508, 604}, {509, 604}, {505, 
  603}, {506, 603}, {507, 603}, {508, 603}, {509, 603}, {510, 
  603}, {505, 602}, {506, 602}, {507, 602}, {508, 602}, {509, 
  602}, {510, 602}, {505, 601}, {506, 601}, {507, 601}, {508, 
  601}, {509, 601}, {510, 601}, {505, 600}, {506, 600}, {507, 
  600}, {508, 600}, {509, 600}, {510, 600}, {506, 599}, {507, 
  599}, {508, 599}, {509, 599}, {510, 599}} *)
```

Now we can gauge dimension.

```
seglen = N[EuclideanDistance[reddot[[1]], yelseg[[-1]]]]

(* Out[71]= 118.562219952 *)
```

THis means 100 pixels is around 118-119 km. So with that normalization we can estimate the area in km^2.

```
seaarea*(100/seglen)^2

(* Out[72]= 451257.736359 *)
```

How did we do?

```
In[77]:= WolframAlpha["surface area of Black Sea in km^2", "Result"]

(* Out[77]= Quantity[4.364*10^5, ("Kilometers")^2] *)
```

Not bad, at that.